# How to convert hdf5 to tensorflow checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection

I am working on Mask-rcnn (https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) and want to convert the Keras checkpoints in h5 format to Tensorflow checkpoints. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load the keras model, then use the tensorflow session to save it as usual:

```
model = keras.models.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
session = keras.backend.get_session()

saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(session, "checkpoints/mask_rcnn.ckpt")
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me in `tensorflow 2.x`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model

saver = tf.train.Checkpoint()
model = load_model('model.hdf5', compile=False)
sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()

save_path = saver.save("model.ckpt")
```